# Get specific column data from shell_exe('df -h') as an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, shell-exec, diskspace

I need to build a script that will query a remote storage server with multiple drives for their free space.

I simply login with SSH, run `df` and throw the output into a variable. Which looks like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
    [1] => /dev/sda1             59392320  14949240  41426064  27% /
    [2] => /dev/sdd1            140592240 114503840  18946708  86% /home/overflow
    [3] => /dev/sdf1            287826944 273844324         0 100% /home/node2
    [4] => /dev/sde1            287826944 253278964  19927228  93% /home/node3
    [5] => /dev/sdg1            287826944   4771768 268434424   2% /home/node4
    [6] => /dev/sdh1            287826944   4329780 268876412   2% /home/node5
    [7] => /dev/sdi1            488302976 439077756  24420864  95% /home/node1
    [8] => /dev/sdh1            287826944   4329780 268876412   2% /home/mnode6
    [9] => /dev/sdh1            287826944   4329780 268876412   2% /home/mnode7
    [10] => tmpfs                  3145728         0   3145728   0% /tmp
)
```

I need to extract how much free space each "node" or "mnode" has. So perhaps a nice array that has pairs such as this:

```
mnode1 => 24000000
node1 => 24000000
node2 => 0
node3 => 20000000
```

Comment: What is the question? How to tokenize the output of df?  If so, awk or perl would do the job.

Comment: I want to extract free space of each node in php.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918261/how-to-maipulate-the-shell-output-in-php

Answer (score 4):

Use `explode(' ', preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $line))` to get an array with all values split up.

Answer (score 0):

To generate an associative array where the keys are from `Mounted On` values and the values are from `Available` values, you can loop over and parse the lines of the `shell_exec('df')` output string (ignoring the headers in the first line) and use `sscanf()` to parse the data into the desired associative array.  `%*s` will match non-whitespace characters, but not capture the match for returning.  I'll use array destructuring (accessing the 2nd element before the 1st element to minimize the total number of variables declared.

Code:

```
$result = [];
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, rtrim(shell_exec('df'))) as $i => $line) {
    if ($i) {
        [1 => $mountedOn, 0 => $result[$mountedOn]] = sscanf($line, '%*s %*d %*d %d %*s %s');
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
[
    '/' => 41426064,
    '/home/overflow' => 18946708,
    '/home/node2' => 0,
    '/home/node3' => 19927228,
    '/home/node4' => 268434424,
    '/home/node5' => 268876412,
    '/home/node1' => 24420864,
    '/home/mnode6' => 268876412,
    '/home/mnode7' => 268876412,
    '/tmp' => 3145728,
]
```

I have also posted an answer to a very similar question: [Display only specific columns of disk usage data from shell_exec('df')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77219643/2943403)